# Release java applet resources when browsing to a URL via code

Tags: java, safari, applet, resource-cleanup

I have a Java applet that presents a JButton that allows users to navigate to another URL (which has a feedback form).

Problem: when I navigate to the form in Safari from the applet, typing into the form is garbled or impossible (only every 10th keystroke or so is actually entered).

Manually terminating the Java Web Plug-in for Safari fixes this immediately.  I assume that I am somehow not releasing resources properly in my applet.  I am aware that cleanup should be performed in the stop() method, but I'm not sure what resources I am failing to release that could cause this kind of behavior.

Here is the code that browses to the URL:

```
final JButton btnLaunch = new JButton("Go to survey");
final myJApplet mj = this;
    btnLaunch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String url ="www.mywebform.example";

            try {
                getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL(url));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(btnLaunch).dispose();
                mj.stop();
            }
      }
```

My best guess is that somehow Safari is mishandling resources by passing them to some Java ActionListener.  However, including:

```
btnLaunch.removeActionListener(this);
```

in a `finally` block does not seem to help.  I have other action listeners in my applet that I know are not explicitly destroyed, but I was under the assumption that generally this wasn't a problem as they are supposed to be disposed of automatically.

EDIT:  Checking through my code, it seems I only have MouseListener or ActionListeners (on JButtons).  So it is even more baffling that I'm having a *keyboard* issue.  I tried manually removing them all in the stop method of the applet (which I manually call in the finally block), but it didn't help.  MouseEvents and ActionEvents shouldn't continue to run upon navigating away from the page!

EDIT 2:  Further information: having the applet open a new window which then contains a link to the final survey also does not work.  However, making the link open in a new window (using html's target="_blank") seems to correct the problem.  So for a work around, I have the applet direct users to a splash page which thanks them and then presents a link for the final survey.  This is annoyingly kludgey, and doesn't answer the original question, but for now it seems like what I will be going with.